# Как сделать блок таким без использования лишних <div>

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend, site

[image: Макет блока]

Пока что я додумался сделать это дивами. Возможно ли сделать это проще и без лишних дивов

```html
 <article style="display: flex;">
        <div>
            <h2>заголовок</h2>
            <h4>текст</h4>
        </div>
        <img src="" alt="картинка">
 </article>
```

Comment: "*и без лишних дивов*" ............ в коде лишь **один див**

Comment: это примерный код, если писать масштабную страницу они будуд занимать много строк

Comment: У вас в вопросе **конкретная картинка** и **конкретный код** её касающийся. Но при этом вы упоминаете какой-то абстрактный большой код.........вопрос тогда у вас в чём? он касается текущего кода и картинки? Если да - то к чему было предложение про масштабную страницу? Если нет - то зачем он представлен и ни слова про проблему о масшабных страницах

Comment: Мой вопрос в том можно ли сделать эту задачу без дива, какое значение имеет то где она будет.

Comment: Вот и я не понимаю зачем вы ляпнули что-то про большой код и масштабную страницу

Comment: Не ясно чем текущий код не угодил. Ну будет один див - ничего критичного нет. Даже если можно сделать без него. Вообще вариантов вёрстки может быть много. Но один див погоды не делает

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте о [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

```css
/* Стили в этом css только для того чтобы лучше показать результат */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

article * {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Основная конструкция описана в html -->
<article style="display: grid; grid: 'title image' auto 'text image' 1fr / 1fr 1fr;">
  <h2 style="grid-area: title">заголовок</h2>
  <h4 style="grid-area: text">текст</h4>
  <img src="" alt="картинка" style="grid-area: image">
</article>
```